# How to join two fields in SelectList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

so the code below gives me a DropDown box with a list of names from Drivers, however it is only firstnames and I have surnames as well, how would I do this.  The code I have is...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DriverId, new SelectList(Model.Drivers, "Id", "FirstName", Model.DriverId), "<Select Driver>")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DriverId)
```

This selects the FirstName, so say "John", I want it to be "John Smith", so it includes the Surname as well.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could make a property in your `Drivers`model:

```
public string FullName
{
  get
  {
  return firstName + " " + LastName;
  }
}
```

then in your view, just change "FirstName" to "FullName", like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DriverId, new SelectList(Model.Drivers, "Id", "FullName", Model.DriverId), "<Select Driver>")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that from your model by concatenating the FirstName and Surname and use that in your dropdown

```
public class DriverViewModel
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }
   public string FullName
   {
      get 
      {
         return Surname+" "+FirstName; //String.Format("{0} {1}", Surname, FirstName);
      }
   }
}
```